How to handle arbitrary amount of quoted arguments?
I want a function that handles an arbitrary amount of quoted symbols.
(define (f . args)
  (if (empty? args)
      '()
      (match (first args)
        ['one   (cons 1 (f (rest args)))]
        ['two   (cons 2 (f (rest args)))]
        ['three (cons 3 (f (rest args)))])))

Running this however
(f 'one 'two 'three)

gives an error
match: no matching clause for '(two three)

Obviously I'm misunderstanding something about how quotes, symbols, datums, etc. all work. How would you write a function that does this?

When you call f recursively in the match clauses, you're passing a list as its only argument. Because the function is defined with a dot-rest lambda list, args is a list of one element, that is itself a list (arg is '((two three)) for example), that fails all of the match conditions.
One fix is to use (apply f (rest args)) when recursing. Or you could have a helper function that takes a single list argument that the top level f calls that calls itself, not f, when it recurses.
(define (f . args)
  (define (helper args)
    (if (empty? args)
        '()
        (match (first args)
          ['one   (cons 1 (helper (rest args)))]
          ['two   (cons 2 (helper (rest args)))]
          ['three (cons 3 (helper (rest args)))])))
  (helper args))

Alternatively, a named let could be used.

The match expression is like a lookup in a dictionary.
(define (lookup x)
  (match x
    ('one 1)
    ('two 2)
    ('three 3)))

(define (f lst)
  (if (empty? lst)
      '()
      (cons (lookup (car lst)) 
            (f (cdr lst)))))

That is the normal way to write it.
But if you want the variadic way, then you could now just do:
(define (f* . args)
  (f args))

(f* 'one 'two 'three)
;; => '(1 2 3)

and later you can do:
(define ht (make-hash))

(hash-set! ht 'one 1)
(hash-set! ht 'two 2)
(hash-set! ht 'three 3)

;; or alltogether:
(hash-set*! ht 'one 1 'two 2 'three 3)

;; and for the lookup define:
(define (lookup k (ht ht))
  (hash-ref ht k))

And you can use f or f* but has now a hash-table which you can extend as you want.
A function like
(define (update-hash ht keys values)
  (map (lambda (k v) (hash-set! ht k v))  keys values))

would be very useful to feed the hash table quickly with more keys and values.

Changing (f ...) to (apply f ...) was the change that came to mind, but zooming out from the implementation details, it's just map -
(define (lookup x)
  (match x
    ('one 1)
    ('two 2)
    ('three 3)))

(map lookup '(two one two))
;; '(2 1 2)

Separating the lookup from the list construction means you can provide different lookup tables in different contexts. To bind a specific lookup and provide variadic interface -
(define (f . args)
  (map lookup args))

(f 'two 'one 'two)
;; '(2 1 2)

Or a variadic interface with a lookup parameter -
(define (f lookup . args)
  (map lookup args))

(f lookup 'two 'one 'two)
;; '(2 1 2)

(f (lambda (x)
      (match x
        ('one "")
        ('two ""))) 'two 'one 'two)

;; '("" "" "")

